# Breaking down Wald CI, Wilson CI, and Agresti-Coull CI

Tags: r, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, proportion

I'm supposed to be writing R functions to calculate the Wald CI, Wilson CI, and Agresti-Coull CI for binomial proportion, I have a source that provides the equations, but I am completely lost. I am looking at the equations, but have no clue where I am supposed to be getting all the values I need.

Ward CI = $p̂ ± k n^{-1/2} (p̂q̂)^{1/2}$

Wilson CI = $(X+k^2/2)/(n+k^2)±(kn^{1/2})/(n+k^2)((p̂q̂+k^2)/(4n))^{1/2}$

Agresti-Coull CI = $p̂ ± k(p̂q̂)^{1/2}n̂^{1/2}$

I'm pretty sure I have most of it, but I am can't figure out what the value of k is. 
n=40
p = 0.2
alpha=0.05
q=0.8
These formulas are from http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213286
I was wondering if anyone could break these down and explain them to me?

Comment: Where did you get the formulas? From something like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval

Comment: The formulas were from formulas 1, 4 , and 5 in this article http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213286

Comment: The article defines the terms (like $\hat{p}$ and $n$) that it uses!

Comment: The one I am really struggling with is K, it says k=Z(alpha/2) but how do I get Z?

Comment: The article defines $z$ also -- right before equation 1 it says $\kappa=z_{\alpha/2}=\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)$

Comment: I see that, but have no clue what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is the number of successes. $n$ is the number of trials. $\hat{p}=X/n$. $\hat{q}=1-\hat{p}$.

The article defines $\kappa$ in terms of $z$ and in turn defines $z$ right before equation 1:

> $\kappa=z_{\alpha/2}=\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)$

$\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

$\Phi^{-1}$ is the inverse function of the standard normal cdf.

$\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)$ is the $1-\alpha/2$ upper tail quantile of the normal distribution.

For example for a 95% CI, $1-\alpha=0.95$ so $1-\alpha/2=0.975$ and $\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha/2)\approx 1.96$.

In the article the Agresti-Coull interval is defined in terms of $\tilde{p}$  not $\hat{p}$. However, $\tilde{p}$ is of the same form as $\hat p$ but with an additional $\kappa^2/2$ successes and an additional $\kappa^2/2$ failures. For $\alpha=0.05$ that adds just under $2$ to $X$ and just under $4$ to $n$.

I think that covers all of the terms in equations 1, 4 and 5.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the Φ is or how to calculate that. Is it a standard from a table?

Comment: @Jamie If you're working by hand you'd use [normal tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table). If you're on a computer you call a standard function to evaluate it. Suitable statistical/mathematical function libraries will either offer $Φ$ and $Φ^{-1}$ or the error function ($\text{erf}$) and its inverse from which $Φ$ and $Φ^{-1}$ are readily calculated. In R $Φ$ and $Φ^{-1}$ are given by `pnorm` and `qnorm` respectively. Try `qnorm(0.975)`. See `?Distributions` for a list of links to the various distributions in vanilla R for which the `d`,`p`,`q` and `r` functions work.